# Javascript, where does your 'magic' data come from?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, sockets, socket.io

Coming from the Java Programming Language where all information that can be used in a method must either be part of a class, or passed by parameter, I'm very confused on to where JavaScript magically generates it's very important data.

In this case I'm using Socket.IO and trying to call a login-method after connection, now I could just use an anonymous function, but I personally believe they're really ugly.

Here's my code:

```
socketIO.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log("Connection maid.");
    socket.on('login', login);
});

function login(json) {
    sqlConnection.query('select * FROM Accounts', function(err, rows, fields) {
       if(err) throw err;

        for(var row in rows) {
            if(rows[row].Username == json.username) {
                console.log("Exists");
                socket.emit('login', {nuel: ''});
            }
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see the `login` function is called whenever the socket receives a login message, and the json object is magically passed to it. I have no idea where it comes from or what generates it, nor do I have a clue how to pass additional arguments to the method, because it breaks/overwrites the `magic` data.

The error I'm running into is where **socket** doesn't exist in the current context, because it was not passed to the login function, however when I try to pass it, the object saved as `json` is completely eradicated from existence.... AND WHERE IS THE DATA THAT'S HERE COMING FROM.

I don't understand this at all, How can I pass this information to call the method, without completely breaking everything.

Comment: Can you make a global variable called 'socket', assign it to a socket object, and then bind events to it so it can be accessed from any function inside that scope?

Comment: Plus one just for title:)